# How to grab data from a shared memory segment?

Tags: c, linux, process, shared-memory

This is my server's code :

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

#define FIFONAME "fifo_clientTOserver"
#define SHM_SIZE 1024  /* make it a 1K shared memory segment */


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // create a FIFO named pipe - only if it's not already exists
    if(mkfifo(FIFONAME , 0666) < 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to create a fifo");
        exit(-1);
    }



    /* make the key: */

    key_t key;

    if ((key = ftok("shmdemo.c", 'j')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(1);
    }


    else /* This is not needed, just for success message*/
    {
       printf("ftok success\n");
    }


    // create the shared memory

    int shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(int), S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | IPC_CREAT);

    if ( 0 > shmid )
    {
        perror("shmget"); /*Displays the error message*/
    }

    else /* This is not needed, just for success message*/
    {
       printf("shmget success!\n");
    }


    // pointer to the shared memory
    char *data = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    /* attach to the segment to get a pointer to it: */
    if (data == (char *)(-1))
    {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }


    /**
     *  How to signal to a process :
     *  kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
     */


    return 0;

}
```

My server needs to read from the shared memory segment , a process-id (type `pid_t`) .

How can I read from the shared memory segment the data that some client wrote ?

Comment: Why do you use a shared memory in your case? Can't you just use the fifo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually would suggest you to use Posix shared memory, see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) instead of old (and nearly obsolete) System V shared memory.

If you want to stick to `shmget` (i.e. old System V IPC, see [svipc(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/svipc.7.html)..) you need to call [shmat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmat.2.html)

So you probably want to access your `data` after the successful `shmat` call. You do have some convention about the type and the size of that `data`. You cpuld have a `struct my_shared_data_st` defined in some header (used both by client and server) then you cast `(struct my_shared_data_st*)data` to access it.

You need both `shmget` and `shmat` in both server and client processes.

With shared memory you need some way to synchronize between client and server (i.e. to tell the consumer part that the producer side finished producing that data).

Read [advanced linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and read several times the man pages.

Comment: Just parse it as a `pid_t` ? casting ?

Comment: Why do you speak of `pid_t`? What is the type of the data you are sharing? How do you synchronize?